# LibGDX render method not updating properly?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My game has 3 states, a running state, a pause state and gameOver one. All 3 are monitored by the integer variable `gameState`. When the pause button is pressed, the state should switch to 1(pause). It all works fine when I click the button while in the running state, but if I press it during the gameOver state, it simply ignores the condition set in my render method.

```
if(gameState == 1)
    sb.draw(pausemenu, cam.position.x - 315,cam.viewportHeight / 2 - 625 / 2, 625, 625);

table.setPosition(cam.position.x, 560);

if(gameState == 2){
    sb.draw(gameover, cam.position.x - gameover.getWidth() / 2 - 85 , cam.viewportHeight / 2 - gameover.getHeight() / 2, 600, 500);
    highScoreFont.draw(sb, "Highscore: " + highScore, cam.position.x - highScoreFont.getScaleX() / 2 - 250 , cam.viewportHeight - 425, 500, Align.center, true);
    coinsFont.draw(sb, coins, cam.position.x - 201, cam.viewportHeight - 590, 500, Align.center, false);
    sb.draw(coin, cam.position.x - layout.width / 2 - 51, cam.viewportHeight - 660, 90, 90);
    restartButton.setPosition(cam.position.x - restartButton.getWidth() / 2, 525);
}
```

When I press the button, the sound is played, like it's supposed to, the buttons that should be in the pause state show up fine, but the Pause Menu is not drawn and the gameOver one is not dissapearing. What am I missing? It's like the render method stops checking if the `gameState` has changed after it has been changed to 2.

EDIT:
The update method:

```
if(gameState == 0 && tableVisible){
    table.setVisible(false);
    pauseButton.setVisible(true);
    tableVisible = false;
    restartVisible = false;
}
else if(gameState == 2 && !restartVisible) {
    restartButton.setVisible(true);
    restartVisible = true;
    layout.setText(coinsFont, getCoins() + "");
}
else if(gameState == 1) {
    if(restartVisible) {
        restartButton.setVisible(false);
    }
    pauseButton.setVisible(false);
    if(!tableVisible) {
        table.setVisible(true);
        tableVisible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your button clicks as the code shown doesn't help us diagnose your problem?

Comment: The pause button simply plays a sound a makes gameState = 1

Comment: The code posted looks fine, the error must lie somewhere else. Are you checking the gameState anywhere else?

Comment: Yes, in the update metod. I'll post it above

Answer (score 1):

There is already a sophisticated way to implement game states in the libGDX framework. Instead of implementing `ApplicationListener` you should extend `Game`. Then you move the game state specific code into other classes that implement `Screen`. To switch the game state you should call `setScreen(Screen screen)` in your `Game` class.

Comment: Well, I don't really have the patience to learn this now. Could you please help me with my render method? That is my main priority right now. Later, I'll probably take a look at this method of yours

Comment: @vladutelu Your errors ultimately come from your messy code. By using the above method, you would get much cleaner code that wouldn't need so many if checks which seem to be the bug here.

Comment: Look, man, I am a beginner. I will try to clean my code later. Right now, I really need to fix this bug.

Comment: You might want to listen to this guy. What you are asking is a solution to a problem that you think is a solution to a different (and your actual) problem. Skrelp tries to help you to solve the actual problem

Comment: @p.streef I have already programmed myself a class that takes care of my states. The reason these 3 "states" in my PlayState class are like that is because I need them all in 1 state, so I can quickly switch between them and for the "resume" button to resume from the pause one to the running one . If the pause state was a different class than the running one, it wouldn't be able to resume this quickly/easily.

Comment: We are maybe talking nanoseconds here. If those are that important, drop libgdx and use openGL directly or even better: drop java and use assembly for even more fine grained control over those cpu cycles!

Comment: Ok, but don't you think this problem I am having is...stupid? I mean, it is so simple, yet it can't be fixed! All it has to do is check if the gameState has been changed from 2 to 1! And for some reason, it recognises the change from 0 to 1 or 0 to 2!